# Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms could not be installed because it is not compatible with any of your project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encoding, nuget-package, codepages

I am trying to install `Microsoft.NETCore.Platform` package from ***NuGet*** packages which is needed for `system.text.encoding.codepages` but I am getting an error as:

> Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms could not be installed because it is not compatible with any of your project

Comment: It is possible the package you are attempting to install is below your .NET Framework. More details would be appreciated :)

Comment: What framework are you targeting?

Comment: I'd bet you're targeting .NET Framework, not .NET Core. You don't need the `System.Text.Encoding.Codepages` package in .NET Framework. Why are you trying to add it anyway? Did you encounter some other problem, googled and found some *.NET Core* guide and thought that's the answer to your original problem?

Comment: Microsoft.NETCore.Platform package and system.text.encoding.codepages are both different nuget packages. Can you tell me about the relation between two packages or provide some code  that you are writing?

Comment: Yes, I'm targeting .NET Framework. I want to use Shift-jis encoding which I guess requires System.Text.Encoding.Codepages package which has dependency on Microsoft.NETCore.Platform. So I was trying to install it.

Comment: I have installed Microsoft.NETCore.Platform or system.text.encoding.codepages both. However, I don't reproduce your problem. can you provide more information so  that we could reproduce your problem.